# Trouble copying a file in a Windows batch script

Tags: windows-xp, batch-file, cmd, dos

In Windows XP, I want it to copy the only file matching the pattern, `selenium*.jar` to a local directory.

I have tried:

```
pushd \\remote.mydomain.com\selenium\
FOR %f IN (selenium*.jar) DO copy %f C:\selenium
```

in which `\\remote.mydomain.com` is a shared directory, whose contents are hosted on a remote server.

But I get the error:

```
C:\selenium>pushd \\remote.mydomain.com\selenium\
f was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `%f` with `%%f` in your script. `%f`works only if you entering the command directly at the command prompt, but not in a batch file. And typing `help for` on the command line shows you the manual where this behaviour is described in the second paragraph.